# Make inserted Matplotlib plot have the correct dimensions

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to do a scatter plot on matplotlib with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4,  5])
y = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2])
param = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
x_linspace = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)
y_fit = param[0] * x_linspace + param[1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.plot(x_linspace, y_fit, '--')
```

Now I want to insert a plot  showing the slope of the curve as:

```
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.675, 0.135, 0.2, 0.2])
ax2.plot([0, 2, 2,0], [0,2,0,0], color="k", linewidth=2) # slope 2
ax2.plot([0, 2, 2,0], [0,4,0,0], color="k", linewidth=2) # slope 1
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.text(2.01, 3.75, "2", fontsize=20)
ax2.text(2.01, 1.75, "1", fontsize=20)
```

How can I make the slopes of the insert match with the main plot?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to show reference gradients with the little triangles, so that you can compare the slope `a` of the line fit to the data.

Personally I find fiddling about with different scales mentally challenging, so my instinct is to use an undistorted Cartesian plane using `ax.axis('equal')`.

I think this works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Make data.
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4,  5])
y = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2])

# Fit the model.
a, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
x_linspace = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)
y_fit = a * x_linspace + b

# Make the plot.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.scatter(x,y)
ax.plot(x_linspace, y_fit, '--')
ax.axis('equal')
ax.grid(c='k', alpha=0.2)

ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.675, 0.135, 0.25, 0.25])
for slope in (0.5, 1, 2):
    ax2.plot([0, 1, 1, 0], [0, slope, 0, 0], color="k", linewidth=2)
    ax2.text(1.1, slope, slope, fontsize=12, va='center')
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.axis('equal')

plot.show()
```

I generalized the slopes a bit so you can add more or fewer.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I do not like the equal axis approach.

I checked the size of the bounding box and placed it in a scaled fashion.

Thanks for the note on the for loop for plotting multiple slopes

```
a = ax.get_position()
a = a.get_points()

#scale down to 20%
a = a*0.2
# Plot slope scale

ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.675, 0.135, a[1][0], a[1][1]])


for slope in (0.5, 1, 2):
    ax2.plot([0, 1, 1, 0], [0, slope, 0, 0], color="k", linewidth=2)
    ax2.text(1.1, slope, slope, fontsize=12, va='center')
    ax2.axis('off')
```

Would you be so kind as to cross-check it?

Comment: You will not have excessive white space on the x-axis